# Slider is taking time to load whereas Other Div of the website has been loaded

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I have a slider that I am displaying in my webpage. Here is the HTML that I have written in the body of the HTML to refer the images.

```
<div id="slider" style="padding-top:77px;">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li>
      <img src="img/new_images/1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/new_images/2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/new_images/3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="img/new_images/4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the jQuery code. I am trying to load the slider in `$(document).ready(function ()`.

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            adaptiveHeight: 'true',
            speed: 3000,
            easing: 'ease-in-out',
            auto: true,
            autoHover: true,
            preloadImages : 'all',
            pager: false
        });
    });
```

Please help me to resolve the issue, as this problem is totally spoiling my website users' experience.

Comment: this problem will occur because your dom will render first and then document.ready event will fire and then bxslider code will execute..you can try to implement a loading image on pageload ...

Comment: @Exception Will you please elaborate your suggestion as answer so that i can grasp the concept..

Comment: @Exception R u helping me sir..?

Comment: just try it and tell if any problem occurs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is general while using jquery..let me explain..when we use `$(document).ready` in jquery firstly your DOM will first load i.e your HTML will render first and then `$(document).ready` event will fire and then the code inside `$(document).ready` will execute which will take flicker of a time atleast ,so in your problem you can implement a loading image on page load i.e when your page first loads display a loading image so that when your `bxSlider` will complete loading then you can hide loading image something as shown below :

Place this div anywhere on page.

```
<div style="display:none" id="loading"><img src="~/Images/Busy-loading.gif" style="width:50px;height:50px" /></div>
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery.fn.center = function () {
        this.css("position", "fixed");
        this.css("top", ($(window).height() / 2) - (this.outerHeight() / 2));
        this.css("left", ($(window).width() / 2) - (this.outerWidth() / 2));
        return this;
    }  //this function will display your loading div at centre of the page

    $("#loading").center();
    $("body").css({ 'opacity': '0.5', 'background-color': '#F0F0F0' });
    $("#loading").show();

  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        adaptiveHeight: 'true',
        speed: 3000,
        easing: 'ease-in-out',
        auto: true,
        autoHover: true,
        preloadImages : 'all',
        pager: false
   });
   $("#loading").hide();
   $("body").css({ 'opacity': '1', 'background-color': '#FFFFFF' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir but i will say that it will not be good to show the loading image in the main page of the website.is there any other way as you was saying to put the things in `page load`

Comment: well..there is not any other good solution as far as my knowledge goes...and i was saying that to implement loading image in page load..thanks..@user3924730

Comment: OK Sir Thanks again. I am implementing it in my website and will let you know regarding the working .Thanks

Comment: I am sorry to say you that my problem still persists as it is.Also i can see that we are putting the qjuery code in `$(document).ready(function ()` and not in page load or window.onload().Any suggestions..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60372/discussion-between-user3924730-and-exception).